How to prove a function is Morse
In general, if I have a function $g:X \rightarrow R$ defined on a manifold $X$, how can I show it is a Morse function?
Is the best way to just compute $g \circ \phi$, where $\phi$ is a parametrization of $X$? Are there any other and less tiring aawys of doing it.
For example, if I consider $C= \{ (x,y):x^2+4y^2=1 \}$ then I´m asked the following:
If $h_P: C \rightarrow R$ is the function that gives the square of the distance between points in the ellipse and P, ie, $h_P(x,y)=(x-p_1)^2+(y-p_2)^2$, for what points P=($p_1,p_2$) is this Morse?
If someone could help me I would really apreciate. Thank you!

Yes, try parametrizing $C$.

Ok, so I get $h_P \circ \phi (\theta)=(cos(\theta)-p_1)^2+(1/2sin(\theta)-p_2)^2$, but if I differentiate this and try to see where it is zero, it´s too much computations.

You need to find a parameterization of the specific curve $C$ given to you. Also, you should state your parameterization explicitly.

And you should also plunge ahead with the computation. It's not too much.

Ok, so a I´m using the parametrization $\phi(\theta) \rightarrow (cos(\theta),1/2sin(\theta))$, and $(h_P \circ \phi)'(\theta)=-2sin(\theta)(cos(\theta)-p_1)+cos(\theta)(1/2sin(\theta)-p_2)$ or $-6sin(2\theta)+2p_1sin(\theta)-p_2cos(\theta)$. How can I see where this is zero?

Also $(h_P \circ \phi)''(\theta)=-12cos(\theta)+2p_1cos(\theta)+p_2sin(\theta)$

I suggest not using the double angle identity. Write down the equation using LaTeX display mode, i.e., in between $$...$$.

$$-2sin(\theta)(cos(\theta)-p_1)+cos(\theta)(1/2sin(\theta)-p_2)=(h_P \circ \phi)'$$ and $$2sin^2(\theta)+1/2cos^2(\theta)+2(cos(\theta)-p_1)cos(\theta)-(1/2sin(\theta)-p_2)sin(\theta)=(h_P \circ \phi)''$$.

And there could only be degenerated critical points if both equal zero.

You want to solve for all of the critical points. The means finding all solutions for when the first formula equals zero. The second plays no role in that step. Once you know where the critical points are, you evaluate the second formula at those points and see if it is nonzero.

Ok, I see, but I don´t know how to find all solutions for when the fisrt is 0, could you help me, please?
